# Solve the following linear equation in two variables using Cramer's rule: $3x-5y=16$ ; $x-3y=-8$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm unable to solve the given linear equation two variables by Cramer's rule. Can somebody please help me with the question, with a detailed answer.

$3x-5y=16$ ; $x-3y=-8$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

$$3x-5y=16$$
$$x-3y=-8$$

$$
\Delta = 
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & -5 \\
1 & -3
\end{vmatrix}
= -4
$$

$$
\Delta_x = 
\begin{vmatrix}
16 & -5\\
-8 & -3
\end{vmatrix}
= -88
$$

$$
\Delta_y = 
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 16\\
1 & -8
\end{vmatrix}
= -40
$$

$$x = \frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta} = 22$$
$$y = \frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta} = 10$$

The problem is a direct application of Cramer's rule in its standard form. I think you should re-read how to apply the rule again.

Comment: please don't answer no effort questions

Comment: @SineoftheTime Okay